# Populating SecurityStamp for legacy users in database in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-identity

I have a legacy database that I am using with ASP.NET Identity.  In order to use the Identity functions a SecurityStamp value is required in the database for each user.

Some have mentioned in other questions relating to this that the value can be 'any random value, EG a random int' but that doesn't sound right to me!?

I created a new user in the database using this code:

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

and it populated it with the following value: `cea9a659-e965-4e76-8203-ed1c79491fa7`

That seems like a more 'secure' value to me than a random `int`, especially when it's called the `SecurityStamp`, it seems like it should be populated in the same manner for all users in my database.

How can I populate the `SecurityStamp` values for my Users database, properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Security Stamp by default is GUID and I have not seen any way to modify it. So you if you want to populate that value for all existing users just run sql:

```
update AspNetUsers
set SecurityStamp = NEWID()
where SecurityStamp is null
```

Answer (score 2):

So the security stamp can be any string you like, its just used to as a comparison point, so you are free to seed all of these to whatever value you want initially (even a constant empty string would work fine), by default the UserManger will generate a new guid for the stamp automatically during these methods:

```
Create
RemovePassword
ChangePassword
AddPassword
RemoveLogin
SetEmail
SetPhoneNumber
ChangePhoneNumber
SetTwoFactorEnabled
```

And you can always call UpdateSecurityStamp directly.

Finally if you are using the Identity.EF implementation, you can always just directly set the field as well:

```
user.SecurityStamp = generateAString();
await userManager.UpdateAsyc(user);
```