# ASP.NET Identity using MySQL as external storage: No SecurityStamp

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm currently writing an ASP.NET MVC app using the standard 'Individual User Accounts' for authentication. I've changed the default storage from a local .mdf file to a MySQL database which follows the same schema.

Everything works fine, and `UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);` writes a new user into the MySQL DB as expected. The only field missing (and therefore `NULL` in the DB) is the `SecurityStamp`. Somehow the usage of MySQL prevents the ASP.NET Identity functionality from writing the column successfully.

I've had a closer look into the local storage in form of the .mdf file, but it does not seem like the `SecurityStamp` is created on the DB itself by any kind of trigger or function.

Debugging and watching the `user` instance after calling `UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);` confirms that the property is `null`:
[image]

As I'm using the standard functionality and only changed the database, I'm not sure how I'd set the `SecurityStamp` myself. Ideally, I would prefer to use the built in creation of such a nonce. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

**On existing Questions:**
I'm aware that there are existing questions regarding the `SecurityStamp` which are solved by setting a a random/unique value for the SecurityStamp explicitly. I would like to solve this case specifically for MySQL and **maintain the default behavior of CreateAsync which already provides code to create a secure SecurityStamp**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating SecurityStamp for legacy users in database in ASP.NET Identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962245/populating-securitystamp-for-legacy-users-in-database-in-asp-net-identity)

Comment: The existing questions, as well as some other related questsions are solved by setting a random/unique value for the `SecurityStamp` explicitly. I would like to solve this case specifically for MySQL and maintain the default behavior of CreateAsync which already provides code to create a secure `SecurityStamp`.

Comment: The code for ASP.Net Identity is open source. So, you can go find out how this all works yourself. I think you may find that it doesn't create a security stamp by default, and that you will have to do that yourself.